# Do I need "the" in this sentence

Tags: definite-article

> We use text features such as textual delimiters, keywords, constants or text patterns, which we call anchors, **to identify data regions** on a web page. Using these anchors, we create patterns for [**the**] data regions and match them in a mixed bottom-up and top-down manner.

The first sentence speaks about *data regions* in general. Could ti be in the case of the second sentence? or I'd better to use "the" to say these data regions are the same data regions we pointed in the previous sentence?

Comment: You have it exactly right. You need to say ***the** data regions* in your second sentence, because you've already identified the ones you're referring to.

Comment: Especially because you use "anchors" generally and then reference them with "these", in the same way, you should reference the general "data regions" from the previous sentence with "the".

Answer (score 1):

Using *the* with the second "data regions" really only implies a specific group of data regions, not necessarily the ones you refers to at first.

Of course, it could be implied depending on how the example is understood.

To be clear, I would use *those* to clarify the relationship.

> We use text features such as textual delimiters, keywords, constants or text patterns, which we call anchors, to identify *data regions* on a web page. Using these anchors, we create patterns for **those** *data regions* and match them in a mixed bottom-up and top-down manner.

Comment: Thank you, I don't care to refer to those data region, I may want or not. I want also to know can I use it simply without "the"?

Comment: If you want to use "data regions" as a general term (not specified in other references in your text), you should leave out the "the".